# Is there a way to count occurrences of a number in an array based on a single column value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

| Category | Score 1 | Score 2 | Score 3 | Score 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 6 |

I'm trying to count the unique instances of each score for each category across the range of Scores. For example in the above. The total instances of a Score '4' for Category 4 across all Scores is: 4

I have tried a Countifs statement, however this does not seem to work across a range of columns and returns a #VALUE error

```
=COUNTIFs(A1:A5,"4",B1:E5,"2")
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output, and perhaps give an example with different numbers (rather than 4 all the time)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the following:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=LET(u,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:E5))),HSTACK(u,COUNTIFS(B2:E5,u)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(B2:E5),
     b,TOROW(B2:E5),
     c,N(a=b),
     SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(a,MMULT(c,a^0)))))
```

---